# TSQL: Merge two sets with grouping and concatenation on the values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables with 2+ million rows in each. I need to merge them and the performance is very important.

The flags need to get concatenated after merge.

**Table 1**

```
ip       flags
-----------
23.4.2.8  x
94.4.7.3  t
12.5.7.9  x
33.1.2.3  xc
```

**Table 2**

```
ip       flags
-----------
23.4.2.8  y
94.4.7.3  t
99.6.7.9  t
```

**Table 3** - merged flags on both tables

```
ip       flags
-----------
23.4.2.8  yx  -- merged flags, the order of flags is not important
94.4.7.3  t   -- merged flags, but distinct
12.5.7.9  x
33.1.2.3  xc
99.6.7.9  t
```

I have this working in C# and wonder if it is possible to do this using SQL. Is there a SQL command that can do this in efficient way?

Comment: Do the two flags (xc) on 33.1.2.3 in table1 need to be treated distinctly? I mean, if table2 had 33.1.2.3->x, would table3 have 33.1.2.3->xxc or 33.1.2.3->xc?

Comment: 33.1.2.3 would remain xc... the flags are distinct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how wide your tables are, but something like below could work:

```
SELECT ISNULL(t.IP, t2.IP) AS IP
    , CONCAT(ISNULL(t.flags,’’), ISNULL(t2.flags, ‘’)) AS flags
FROM table1 as t
FULL JOIN table2 as t2 ON t.IP = t2.IP
```

Comment: Thanks! This works really fast! See answer posted by me with your code.

Answer (score 2):

Another option if you don't have SQL Server 2017+ using `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH()` - I think it's good for 2008 +

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6317bf/5/0)

```
SELECT 
    ip
    ,STUFF((SELECT  ',' + t.flags
            FROM(
                SELECT ip, flags 
                FROM table1
                UNION ALL
                SELECT ip, flags 
                FROM table2
                )t
            WHERE t.ip = a.ip
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS Flags
FROM
(
    SELECT ip, flags 
    FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ip, flags 
    FROM table2
)a
GROUP BY ip
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention which version of SQL Server you're using, though if it is 2017+ this solution will work for you.
You can accomplish your goal using `STRING_AGG`. Try the following with your data (create tables based off of your sample data above)

```
CREATE TABLE #table1(
    ip VARCHAR(100)
    ,flags CHAR(10)
)
GO
CREATE TABLE #table2(
    ip VARCHAR(100)
    ,flags CHAR(10)
)
GO

INSERT INTO #table1 VALUES 
('23.4.2.8','x')
,('94.4.7.3','t')
,('12.5.7.9','x')
,('33.1.2.3','xc')
GO 

INSERT INTO #table2 VALUES 
 ('23.4.2.8','y')
,('94.4.7.3','t')
,('99.6.7.9','t')

GO 

SELECT 
    ip
    ,STRING_AGG(RTRIM(flags),',')
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ip
        ,flags 
    FROM #table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        ip
        ,flags 
    FROM #table2
)a
GROUP BY ip
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this didn't work for me. Our SQL has compatibility 130, version 13.0...

Comment: @realPro I had thought about the XML PATH approach, though STRING_AGG is much more elegant, and I wasn't sure what version you were using. The answer provided by BJones seems to be what I would have done prior to String_AGG

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the answer by ssn to clean the duplicate characters. 
The performance is really good!

```
SELECT ISNULL(t.IP, t2.IP) AS IP
    , [dbo].[FN_CLEANDUPCHAR](CONCAT(ISNULL(t.block_reason_code,''), ISNULL(t2.block_reason_code, ''))) AS block_reason_code 
FROM ##table1 as t FULL JOIN ##table2 as t2 
ON t.IP = t2.IP
```

And this is the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_CLEANDUPCHAR]
(
    @S varchar(20)
)
RETURNS varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        @S = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@s,Number,1),@s) BETWEEN 1 AND Number-1 THEN STUFF(@s,Number,1,'') ELSE @S END
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values
    WHERE Number BETWEEN 2 AND LEN(@s) AND type='P'
    ORDER BY Number DESC

    return @S    
END
GO
```